# Can I use android license manager without publisher account?

Tags: android

It seems that unless I sign up for  publisher account by paying $25, I can not use android license manager service.

How can I use android license manager for android applications which are not going to be put in android market ?

Does anyone know of a free license manager  which can work with android client ?

Comment: You cant access Google play unless you get the paid service. But you can try for some other apps publishers.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/licensing/overview.html#Reqs) reference you can't use it:

> Google Play Licensing is designed to let you apply license controls to
>   applications that you publish through Google Play. The service is not
>   designed to let you control access to applications that are not
>   published through Google Play or that are run on devices that do not
>   offer the Google Play client.